# Translation of “For the following 11 months”

Tags: traduction, adjectifs, indications-de-temps, ordre-des-mots

How do we express in French that an action lasts 11 months from the moment it begins?

I'm not sure if it's supposed to be written like this "Pour les suivants onze mois" or "Pour les onze mois suivants" or something completely different.

Comment: Pour (or pendant, depends on context) les douze mois suivants. But you should give more context, it could also be, les onze mois qui suivent

Comment: You have given too little context, we cannot give you a reliable translation. The answer you have accepted may or may not be correct depending on the context. I am closing this question, please edit it to provide context and we can reopen it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Les onze prochains mois" or "les onze mois suivants" would be the most usual translation for "the following 11 months" to me.

I would translate the "for" with "pendant", "durant" or "pour" depending on context.

Comment: For the next 11 months, he works at his job. Would it be durant or pendant?

Comment: I would go with a simple "Il travaille les onze prochains mois" or "Il travaille pendant/durant les onze prochains mois". Both "durant" and "pendant" are correct here.

Answer (score 0):

Another usual translation (that is pretty much literally translated from the English version you provided) :

- "Il a travaillé pendant les 11 mois qui suivent. (ex: dans cette entreprise)"

Ou un exemple au passé :

- "Il a travaillé (dans cette entreprise) pendant les 11 mois qui suivirent (la mort de sa femme)."

Comment: I'm not sure that the OP said anything about *worked* (past tense).

Comment: Saying it in the present tense does not make much sense. In the future sense, it could become : *Il va travailler (dans cette entreprise) pour les 11 mois qui viennent*.

Comment: Ou *les 11 mois qui viennent*.

Answer (score 0):

In general one would simply say "pour onze mois" or "pendant onze mois" - if the "following" idea is implicit from the context. You should provide more context to be sure.